# How would I display the result of a SQL query in a readable way?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, formatting

I couldn't find a solution on how to easily format the result of a query.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name, email FROM customers")
print(cursor.fetchone())
>>> [('Joe Bloggs', 'joebloggs@jbloggs.com')]
```

I would like the result to be formatted in a way like:

- Name : Joe Bloggs
- Email : joebloggs@jbloggs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
row = cursor.fetchone()[0] #get the only element in array
name = row[0]
email = row[1]
```

And then you can use name and email to format your result.
You also need to look out for when your query returns 0 elements.